# Read numpy array from a Java Float

Tags: python, android, arrays, numpy

I have Java float array that I am posting to a server and reconstructing a numpy array from the received unicode array on the server side like so,

```
# Android, java side 
  JSONObject jsonParams = new JSONObject();
  jsonParams.put("test", new Float[]{0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f});
  StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonParams.toString());

  client.post(this, postEndPoint, entity, "application/json", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
      Log.e("PostToServer","Post has failed!");
    }
  });

# Python flask server side
@app.route("/test", methods=['POST'])
def processdata():
    if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
        params = request.get_json()
        if params.get('test', None) is not None:
            test = params.get('test', None)
            test_val = np.frombuffer(test)
            print(test_val) #!= what I sent 
    return make_response(jsonify({"":""}),200)
```

I tried to set the dtype to `np.float32` etc., Any pointers on how to reconstruct the exact array on the server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely missed the fact that I need to stringify the float array .

You can use gson or like to convert the array easily and post like so,

```
# android side 
Gson gson = new Gson();
jsonParams.put("test", gson.toJson(new Float[]{0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}));

# server side 
if params.get('test', None) is not None:
    test = params.get('test', None)
    if type(test) is unicode: 
        test_val = np.array(test[1:-1].split(','), dtype=float) 
        # strips '[' and ']' and split the rest using ',' and read them into a numpy array
```

Hope this helps someone!